# jQuery show/hide/mouseenter issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four lines of text and I want to display a specific image on `mouseenter` on the right side of each line.

The problem I'm having right now is that all four images are beeing displayed at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/m97qebjr/10

**jQuery:**

```
$(".thumb").hide();
$(".text" ).mouseenter(function() {
$(".thumb").show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
$(".thumb").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery at all: http://jsfiddle.net/m97qebjr/16/

```
.thumb {
    display:none; /* added line */
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.wrap:hover .thumb{ /* added rule */
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Pure CSS is also great... Thanks a lot!

Comment: This shows image when `.wrap` is hovered, his version shows image only when `.text` is hovered.

Comment: I have one last question: Is it possible to display the first image by default? I mean when people load the page, that there is only this one image shown and as soon as you `mouseenter` the other lines it disappears? @RokoC.Buljan @caeth

Answer (score 0):

`$(".thumb")` matches all elements with class thumb. Try this instead:

```
$(".thumb").hide();
$(".text").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".thumb").show();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".thumb").hide();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m97qebjr/13/